# Raspberry Pi Motion Camera Not Working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, motion-detection

I installed motion sensing camera on my Raspberry Pi with [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665518/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera) tutorial.

I worked through everything. I'm using Raspbery Pi 3 Model B so there were a few differences but I think I've covered everything.

When I restart the Pi Motion seems to start as if I run `sudo service motion status` I get something like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service motion status
● motion.service - LSB: Start Motion detection
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/motion)
Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-03-08 21:08:08 UTC; 3min 0s ago
Process: 1271 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/motion stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1277 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/motion start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 08 21:08:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Motion detection.
Mar 08 21:08:08 raspberrypi motion[1277]: Starting motion detection daemon: motion.
```

I can't connect to the browser page from my Mac though. If I use http://:8080 I get an unable to connect error. I did install Apache so If I do http:// I get the default page.

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried http:/[YOUR_IP_ADDRESS]:8081. The 8080 is dedicated to configuration.